# Cronjob not accepting port number in php post

Tags: php, redirect, post, cron, port

Using a php form to post a variable to website

```
$this->redirect("http://Web_Address/httpds?switch=0");
```

This works fine from a normal web browser and from Cronjob.

The problems started when target websites port number got change from 80 to 8081.

```
$this->redirect("http://Web_Address:8081/httpds?switch=0");
```

This still works fine from a web browser but no longer works in Cronjob.

Any ideas how to solve this???

Thanks

Comment: cron calling a php script via the cli, there's no browser, no http headers so how could a redirect work?

Comment: What's the "redirect" code. And as Dagon said, not clear how you can redirect a cron job - what does the cron job do?

Comment: cron reads the php file (Yii Framework) where redirection code is written ie- $this->redirect("http://Web_Address:8081/httpds?switch=0"); but the problem is its not redirecting after adding the port number with the cronjob but if we go to the browser and run the php file it does redirection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of redirect I would use curl in cronjob PHP script, like this:

```
<?php
 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://Web_Address:8081/httpds?switch=0");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

 curl_exec($ch);

 curl_close($ch);
 ?>
```